# PHP library for SVG dynamic graphs

Tags: php, user-interface, graph, svg

I was (quite) happy to use [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/) for graphs in PHP, and when in need of "dynamicity", I just added the image map, handled hover and click events etc. (a bit clumsy in jpgraph, but possible).

But now I've seen [pretty cool graphs made in SVG](http://www.lyzuj.cz/snehova-historie/s%CC%8Cpindleru%CC%8Av-mly%CC%81n-svaty%CC%81-petr-ECZSPINDLER-5831-cs.jhtml?season=2011&tp=1m&report_type=dh&tab=2#destLinks). I didn't know this dynamicity is possible in SVG!

Can you recommend any SVG dynamic graph library for PHP that could replace jpgraph in this sense? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can try - raphael.js

Comment: +1 in hope rather than expectation of getting a *PHP/SVG* answer.  As you can probably tell from the answers so far, all the effort seems to be going into client side javascript / canvas solutions.

Comment: thanks @RobAgar. Can you tell which library was used in the [above link](http://www.lyzuj.cz/snehova-historie/s%CC%8Cpindleru%CC%8Av-mly%CC%81n-svaty%CC%81-petr-ECZSPINDLER-5831-cs.jhtml?season=2011&tp=1m&report_type=dh&tab=2#destLinks)? Was it serverside PHP/SVG or clientside javascript? I would say serverside, but I'm not sure.

Comment: javascript, using HighCharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) judging by the css class names

Comment: Thanks @Rob, the markup in Firebug confused me, I thought it's serverside! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many libraries are using `<canvas>` instead of SVG. Then, it will really depends on your needs, but **D3** is very impressive.

- [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)
- [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: thanks greut. Do you have personal experience with any of those libraries?

Answer (score 3):

Try this Raphael js add-on for charting.
http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Comment: thanks. Do you have any personal experience with this library you can comment on?

Answer (score 0):

From a PHP perspective, have a look at [this](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php), which looks good, maintained and interactive. Not sure if it covers all your dynamicity needs.
Looking for an alternative for jpGraph which started to cause complaints after upgrading the 'P' part in MAMP, I stumbled upon SVGGraph. Didn't convert my graphs to it yet.